# Should OnMethod always raise event (naming convention dilemma)?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

It is common that **OnMethods** are used to raise events.
It is also common to override that method in derived class to add some additional logic instead of attaching to event raised by that method.

Consider now situation like this:
Two classes SceneManager and SceneBase.
SceneManager is responsible for closing/showing/hiding scenes. When SceneManager does this with a scene, it **notifies** the scene about that fact so the scene can take some actions related to its state change.
For that I decided to use virtual methods **OnClose**, **OnShow**, **OnHide** in SceneBase, so SceneManager can notify SceneBase at the right time (instead of attaching SceneBase to SceneManager's events like SceneShownEvent). I thought that this naming convention is most descriptive for me.
But this naming convention (On*MethodName*) is generally reserved for raising events.
OnMethods are usually *protected virtual* so derived classes can add some other logic to OnMethods (instead of attaching to event).
 
So it seems that beside rising event there can be other logic in that method. And not only that, for example Microsoft's Observer's pattern interface has also OnMethods that don't necessary rise events. There are just used for notifying subscriber about state change.
They are

- IObserver.OnNext, which supplies the observer with new or current
  information.
- IObserver.OnError, which informs the observer that an error has
  occurred.
- IObserver.OnCompleted, which indicates that the provider has
  finished sending notifications.

I could name my methods like AfterShown or Shown. But for me OnMethod fits for that scenario best. So the question is:

Is it OK to use name OnMethod as notification method that will not rise event and is called from other class, like in my case? Or I should reserve it only for event rising methods?